# Filtering based on file extension not working in QFileSystemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to filter file system model to show only files with extension .ncr (NCReport templates). The view instead shows all files. Any ideas how to make the filtering work? Thanks.

(I realize there's plenty other clumsiness here, suggestions welcome.)

```
fsmodel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
connect(fsmodel,SIGNAL(rootPathChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(fileSystemModelRootSetSuccessfully()));

// this call is required on windows to show anything in file view
QModelIndex rootIndex=fsmodel->setRootPath(reportdirstring);
// root index could be removed
Q_UNUSED(rootIndex);

fsmodel->setReadOnly(true);

ui->reportTemplateDirView->setModel(fsmodel);
ui->reportTemplateDirView->setRootIndex(fsmodel->index(reportdirstring));
ui->reportTemplateDirView->expandAll();
ui->reportTemplateDirView->header()->hide();

// selecting the first file entry with selectFileInDirView(); requires the qtreeview to be sorted
// sort in desc order since that is the only way to get the first item selected?
ui->reportTemplateDirView->sortByColumn(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
fsmodel->sort(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.ncr";
fsmodel->setNameFilters(filters);
fsmodel->setNameFilterDisables(false);

// hide report template directory view extra columns,
//type?
ui->reportTemplateDirView->setColumnHidden(1,true);
//size?
ui->reportTemplateDirView->setColumnHidden(2,true);
//date
ui->reportTemplateDirView->setColumnHidden(3,true);

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x040700
// as soon as QFileSystemModel has parsed the entire directory tree, tell the QTreeView to expand its hierarchy
// note that if there are a lot of files, this could be too inefficient.
// if problems arise, consider commenting this out or using a QDirModel, which could be equally inefficient though.
connect(fsmodel,SIGNAL(directoryLoaded(QString)),ui->reportTemplateDirView,SLOT(expandAll()));
connect(fsmodel,SIGNAL(directoryLoaded(QString)),this,SLOT(selectFileInDirView()));
#endif

//  show a fake folder name + icon at the top of the folder tree of report template directory
QFileIconProvider iconProvider;
QIcon folderIcon=iconProvider.icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder);
ui->reportTemplatesLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(folderIcon.pixmap(QSize(16,16))));
```

Comment: I have just recreated your example and it working like a charm! What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.5 on MSVC 2013. No other anomalies that I know of.

Comment: Probably you have a problem somewhere in the slot like "selectFileInDirView"? because otherwise it filters files in dirs as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander noted, this actually works. The issue was that I was setting the filters to empty elsewhere. ^.^